# how to set variable for each roles on capistrano3

Tags: capistrano3

Is there way to set variable for each roles?

I wanna set http_proxy variable for only web, not to set for cron.

below code, set variables's scope looks like global, so setting to :git_environment_variables affects to cron.

```
server 'web1', user: 'user', roles: %w(web)
server 'batch1', user: 'user', roles: %w(cron)

task :set_proxy_variables do
  on roles(:web) do
    set :git_environmental_variables, {
      http_proxy: 'http://fp:8080',
      https_proxy: 'http://fp:8080'
    }

    set :bundle_env_variables, {
      http_proxy: 'http://fp:8080',
      https_proxy: 'http://fp:8080'
    }
  end
end
before 'deploy', 'set_proxy_variables'
```